# Javas UUID implementation in Nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, uuid

I'm working in a situation where I have a database that stores UUID data in the form of its "MostSignificantBits" and "leastSignificantBits" in Java, to reconstruct the UUID I simply 
call

`new UUID(mostSigBits, leastSigBits)` 
but I have not been able to find a solid implementation of this in Nodejs that would allow me to reconstruct the UUIDs from Bits.

I've researched over a few repos regarding UUID support in Nodejs but have not had any luck finding the resources I need.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to reconstruct a uuid from bits in Nodejs and convert a uuid into most & least sigBits

Java UUID: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: why https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid not useful?

Comment: So why the Java tag on this Question? Seems his has nothing to do with Java?

Answer (score 0):

I have translated the content of UUID.java to nodeJs,

NB: java use Little Indian, `L4--> .order(true);`

```html
var ByteBuffer = require("bytebuffer");
var Long = require("long");
const uuid64 = "n0w6CLZIZvJ5hRmg9YsMjA==";
let bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(Buffer.from(uuid64, 'base64')).order(true);
const mostSigBits = bb.readLong();
const leastSigBits = bb.readLong();

console.log(UUID(mostSigBits, leastSigBits));
// f26648b6-083a-4c9f-8c0c-8bf5a0198579

function digits(val,digits) {
    let  hi = Long.ONE.shiftLeft(digits*4);
     let hwi = hi.or(val.and(hi.subtract(1)));
    return hwi.toString("16").substring(1);
}

function UUID(mostSigBits, leastSigBits) {
    return (digits(mostSigBits.shiftRight(32), 8) + "-" +
        digits(mostSigBits.shiftRight(16), 4) + "-" +
        digits(mostSigBits, 4) + "-" +
        digits(leastSigBits.shiftRight(48), 4) + "-" +
        digits(leastSigBits, 12) );
}
```